# Find the bifurcation points for the system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

---

Frist of all, I found post [Find the bifurcation points for the following system of ODEs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252036/find-the-bifurcation-points-for-the-following-system-of-odes) by Antonio Vargas and comment by Pragabhava very useful, nevertheless could anyone be pleased to be more specific about the following text in THAT post :

$$f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0) + \pmatrix{(1-y_0) x -x_0 y \\ x -2y_0 y} + \ldots$$

I assume this must be Taylor series of a $f(x,y)$ near the point $(x_0,y_0)$, nevertheless I do not get it.

---

I am also reading paper by John David Crawford about bifurcations and got stuck at some point, if somebody read this article , could you please explain, why when we rewrite our DE as:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\pmatrix{x \\  y} = \pmatrix{y\\ -y-x-x^3}$$ And say let :
$$\dot x = V(\mu,x)$$
So after this equilibrium points can be found from $V(0,0) = 0$, What does it mean?

---

3rd question

I have a bit more complicated system of diff. eq. that is why I can not apply(actually do not know how to apply and repeat the article steps.
For instance if we do the Taylor expansion of the function:
$$\dot x = V(\mu,0) + D(V(\mu,0))+O(x^2)$$
as $V(\mu,0) = 0$ and $O(x^2)$ is not used. then
$$\dot x =  D(V(\mu,0))$$
next step is to make the something like the following matrix:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\pmatrix{x_i \\...\\  x_{i+1}} = \pmatrix{0,0,\lambda\\ ... \\ -\lambda_{i+1},-\lambda_i,- \lambda_i^3} \times \pmatrix{x_i \\...\\  x_{i+1}}$$ 
(that matrix was done to find the solution easier(page 994))
**FINALY, MY question is the following:**
As I said earlier, I have the system of ODE, but a little bit more complicated than in the example in an article, that is why Taylor expansion and further procedures I do not know how to do. **Is it possible to represent the next system of ODE in a matrix form?**

Here is the system:
$$ [  \ddot{\theta} ]=  [ sin(\theta)cos(\theta)(\dot{\phi})^2 + \omega_{af}^2(sin(\theta)^3cos(\theta)cos(\phi)^4+sin(\theta)^3cos(\theta)sin(\phi)^4 - cos(\theta)^3sin(\theta)) ] +  [ 2 \gamma_{af} \dot{\theta}   - 2 j sin(\theta)cos(\theta)cos(\phi)sin(\phi) ]$$
$$[\ddot{\phi}] = - [cot(\theta)\dot{\phi}\dot{\theta}] + [\omega_{af}^2(-sin(\theta)^2cos(\phi)^3sin(\phi) +sin(\theta)^2sin(\phi)^3cos(\phi)) ] + [2\gamma_{af} \dot{\phi}  -   j (cos(\phi)^2 - sin(\phi)^2 ) ] $$
**So, how can I find bifurcation in this system.** My main parameter I can modify is **j**

---

My work to the last question:
if I represent my system in a bit other way( $L_x = sin(\theta)cos(\phi)$, $L_y=sin(\theta)sin(\phi),L_z = cos(\theta)$), then my system looks like this:

$$  \ddot{L_x} = -  \omega_{af}^2 L_x -  2 \gamma_{af} \dot{L_x} - j L_y $$

$$  \ddot{L_y} = -  \omega_{af}^2 L_y -  2 \gamma_{af} \dot{L_y} + j L_x $$
then
$$ A w^2 -  \omega_{af}^2 A - 2 \gamma_{af} A iw - j B  = 0 $$

$$  B w^2  -  \omega_{af}^2 B  - 2 \gamma_{af} B iw + j A = 0 $$
then using De Moivre's formula I get some $w$, however

as the saddle point is when $Re_1 >0, Re_2<0$
 I get nonsense.